# Is the sum of an alternating series satisfies the following inequality

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

> **Question** if $s$ is sum of the alternating series $\sum (-1)^{n+1}z_n$ and if $s_n$ is the nth partial sum then, $|s-s_{n}|≤z_{n+1}$

**My attempt**:

$|s-s_n|=|s-s_{n+1}+s_{n+1}-s_n|$

$$≤|s-s_{n+1}|+|s_{n+1}-s_n|$$

$$≤\epsilon + z_{n+1}$$

($s_n\rightarrow s$ so that, $s_{n+1}\rightarrow s$)

Now as $\epsilon >0$ is arbitrary,  letting $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$,  we havve $|s-s_{n}|≤z_{n+1}$

Is my attempt is correct? Please help....
Is there is any other way?

Comment: As $\epsilon \to 0$ you need greater $n$. So I don't think your argument is right.

Comment: This is not true in general. It _is_ true if the $z_n$ are positive and decreasing, but that is not implied by the words "alternating series".

Answer (score 1):

Here, two cases may arrise,one is when " $(z_n)$ is not monotone " and another is "$(z_n)$ is monotone ".

Case $1$, when $(z_n)$ is not monotone, then your statement is wrong.

Take the example, $z_n = \begin{cases}2^{-n} & \text{ n is even} \\ 3^{-n} & \text{ n is odd }\end{cases}$. ,

The sum, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} z_{n} = \frac{1}{24} $.
Clearly, $|s - s_1|=| \frac{1}{24} - \frac{1}{3} | = \frac{21}{72} > \frac{1}{4} = |z_2| $.

Case $ 2 $ , when $(z_n) $ is monotone,
Since,  $ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1} z_{k} = s $,
Just do, $(s - s_{n}) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1} z_{k} -\sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k+1} z_{k}   =\pm z_{n+1} \mp( ( z_{n+2} - z_{n+3}) + (z_{n+4} - z_{n+5})+( z_{n+6} - z_{n+7}) + ............................      ) $ .

If $(z_{n}) $ is monotone,then , the sum = $( ( z_{n+2} - z_{n+3}) + (z_{n+4} - z_{n+5})+( z_{n+6} - z_{n+7}) + .........) $

must be positive ,

Now take          $( ( z_{n+2} - z_{n+3}) + (z_{n+4} - z_{n+5})+( z_{n+6} - z_{n+7}) + .........) =A $

A is some positive real.
Now,  $(s - s_{n}) = \pm z_{n+1} \mp A = \pm(z_{n+1} - A) $.

Hence, $|s - s_{n}| \le z_{n+1} $

Comment: where is $s$ gone? in RHS of your first line? Here $s_n= z_1+ z_2+...+z_n$ so how you obtain your first line?

Comment: No, $ S_{n} = z_{1} - z_{2} + z_{3 } - z_{4} + ........ $, you say $ S_{n} $ is partial sum of $\sum (-1)^{n+1}z_n$.

Comment: Is this answer still unclear? Please tell me.

Comment: thanks for the reply. My mistake. Now its clear.

Comment: I like to ask, what's about my attempt, is it wrong?

Comment: How do you know $z_{n+1}$ has positive sign? Because may be $n+1$ is odd and so that, $(-1)^{n+1}z_{n+1}= -z_{n+1}$

Comment: That does not imply $(-1)^{n+1} z_{n+1}$ is positve

Comment: By the way $ n+1 $ th term is $(-1)^{n+2} z_{n+1} $. Please check the series.

Comment: Then what? Take $n=5$ then $(-1)^{n+2} z_{n+1}= (-1)^7 z_{n+1}= -z_{n+1}$

Comment: Ok, now you can say, $ n+2 $ can be odd, so, then $ n+1 $ th term is $-z_{n+1} $. You can see that at the last line I take modulus of $(S - S_{n}) $, and since $(S - S_{n}) = - z_{n+1} - a $ , $ a $ is some positive real, as I proved before. Now you can see what happen if I take modulus on $(S - S_{n}) $

Comment: I do some edit.

Comment: Is it still having any doubts? You can tell. Also , thanks for pointing that missing part.

Comment: Where does the question say that $(z_n)$ is monotonic? I don't think that this is implied by the words [alternating series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series).

Comment: @TonyK it's definition of an alternating series. You can check that.

Comment: Yes, I just checked it. See my link.

Comment: @TonyK you are right, it is possible iff the series is convergent.

Comment: _What_ is possible iff the series is convergent? (The OP's statement is not true even with that assumption, if the $z_n$ are not monotonic.)

Comment: Hmm, if the series is divergent, it is automatically not possible. If you say only about monotoneous, then also it is not possible by taking the sequence $(n) $

Comment: You are not making sense any more.

Comment: @TonyK Where do I make no sense?

Comment: @TonyK OP already said that the series is convergent. Please notice.

Comment: Yes, but they didn't say that $(z_n)$ is monotonic. So the OP's statement is not true. Please notice.

Comment: @TonyK By, alternating series test, convergent alternating series implies  $(z_n)$ is monotone decreasing sequence of positive terms with converging to $ 0 $, and it is in the link, what you have given.

Comment: Oh good heavens. You have it backwards, Subhajit. The alternating series test says that _if_ the sequence is monotone decreasing, _then_ the OP's statement is true. It doesn't say that if an alternating series converges, then $(z_n)$ is monotone decreasing. Of course it doesn't say that, because it's not true. Please notice.

Comment: @TonyK okk, I mixed up, sorry and very much thanks for pointing the fault , thanks! So, OP's statement is false untill he add the monotonous part.

Comment: @TonyK I do some edits, can you please tell me, is this correct or not?