# Question about sum of an alternating series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> **Question** if $s$ is sum of the alternating series $\sum (-1)^{n+1}z_n$ and if $s_n$ is the nth partial sum then, $|s-s_{n}|≤z_{n+1}$

I had asked this question already here
[Is the sum of an alternating series satisfies the following inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3768381/168676)

but, i think answer that posted is not correct.

How is assumed that, $(z_n)$ is monotonic?

Answer goes like this

$(s - s_{n}) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1} z_{k} -\sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k+1} z_{k}   = z_{n+1} -( ( z_{n+2} - z_{n+3}) + (z_{n+4} - z_{n+5})+( z_{n+6} - z_{n+7}) + ............................      ) $

How he know $(-1)^{n+2}z_{n+1}=z_{n+1}$  is $n+2$ is even? This is not mentioned anywhere. Something wrong with this answer. Please help me in Question.

Comment: @mwt no it did not answer my question.

Comment: I don't understand why negative votes. When someone need help and trying to make efforts to understand solution

Comment: I agree, you do not deserve any downvote.

Comment: Subhajit has just proved that there are sequence $\left\{z_n\right\}$ such that the alternating series is convergent and the inequality $|s-s_n|\le z_{n+1}$ is wrong. So it is necessary to add some hypothesis in order to prove the inequality. I have add monotony, but if you do not like it, in any case you have to add some other hypothesis in order to prove the inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Subhajit has already proved that there are sequences $\left\{z_n\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of non-negative real numbers such that the alternating series $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}z_n$ is convergent and the inequality $|s-s_n|\le z_{n+1}$ is wrong.
For example, $z_n = \begin{cases}2^{-n} & \text{ n is even} \\ 3^{-n} & \text{ n is odd }\end{cases}$.

So if we wish the inequality would always hold without exceptions, it is necessary to add some hypothesis. I am going to add monotony, but if you do not like it, in any case, you have to add some other hypothesis in order to prove the inequality.

Let $\left\{z_n\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of non-negative real numbers such that $z_n\ge z_{n+1}\;\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\;\;\text{and}\;\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}z_n=0.\\\text{Let }s\text{ be the sum of the alternating series}\;\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}z_n\;\text{and}\\\text{let } s_n \text{ be the } n^{th} \text{ partial sum.}$

Since $\;z_{2m+1}\ge z_{2m+2}\;\forall m\in\mathbb{N},\;$ it follows that

$s_{2m+2}-s_{2m}=z_{2m+1}-z_{2m+2}\ge0\;\;\forall m\in\mathbb{N},\;$ therefore

$s_{2m+2}\ge s_{2m}\;\;\forall m\in\mathbb{N}$.

Hence, $\;\;s_{2m}\le s_{2m+2}\le \sup_\limits{m\in\mathbb{N}}\left\{s_{2m}\right\}=\lim_\limits{m\to\infty} s_{2m}=s.\;\;(*)$

Since $\;z_{2m}\ge z_{2m+1}\;\forall m\in\mathbb{N},\;$ it follows that

$s_{2m+1}-s_{2m-1}=z_{2m+1}-z_{2m}\le0\;\;\forall m\in\mathbb{N},\;$ therefore

$s_{2m+1}\le s_{2m-1}\;\;\;\forall m\in\mathbb{N}$.

Hence, $\;\;s=\lim_\limits{m\to\infty} s_{2m-1}=\inf_\limits{m\in\mathbb{N}}\left\{s_{2m-1}\right\}\le s_{2m+1}\le s_{2m-1}.\;\;(**)$

From $(*)$ and $(**)$ it follows that

$s_{2m}\le s_{2m+2}\le s\le s_{2m+1}\le s_{2m-1}\;\;\forall m\in\mathbb{N}.$

Therefore

$|s-s_{2m-1}|=s_{2m-1}-s\le s_{2m-1}-s_{2m}=z_{2m}\;\;\forall m\in\mathbb{N}$,

$|s-s_{2m}|=s-s_{2m}\le s_{2m+1}-s_{2m}=z_{2m+1}\;\;\forall m\in\mathbb{N}$.

Hence, in any case it results that

$|s-s_{n}|\le z_{n+1}\;\;\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.
$$$$**REMARK:**

In this question the series is convergent for hypothesis, but more generally, if $\left\{z_n\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is not a monotonic sequence, the alternating series $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}z_n$ could be not convergent (even though $z_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$).

For example if $\left\{z_n\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is the following sequence:

$z_{2m-1}=\frac{1}{m}\;$ for all $\;m\in\mathbb{N}$,

$z_{2m}=\frac{1}{m(m+1)}\;$ for all $\;m\in\mathbb{N}$,

the series

$\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}z_n=1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{20}+\ldots$

is not convergent, indeed

$s_{2p}=\sum_\limits{n=1}^{2p}(-1)^{n+1}z_n=\sum_\limits{m=1}^{p} \left(z_{2m-1}-z_{2m}\right)=\sum_\limits{m=1}^{p} \left(\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{m(m+1)}\right)=\sum_\limits{m=1}^{p}\frac{1}{m+1}$

and $\lim_\limits{p\to\infty}s_{2p}=+\infty$.

My remark does not mean that there is not any sequence $\left\{z_n\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ non-monotonic for which the alternating series $\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}z_n$ is convergent, in fact there are a lot of them.

My remark only means that without the monotony hypothesis, not all the alternating series are convergent, in fact monotony is a sufficient condition for the convergence of the series, but obviously it is not a necessary condition.

Comment: How do you know $(z_{n})$ is monotone?

Comment: How, we can assume, $(z_n)$ is monotone sequence

Comment: @Angelo , how could you say sequence $\{z_n\} $ is even monotone?

Comment: It is simply not true that monotonicity is necessary - for once $z_n$ can be absolutely convergent arbitrary, for another one can modify $z_n$ by an absolutely convergent series and still preserves convergent (taking $z_n =1/n-1/(n\sqrt n), n$ odd, $z_n=1/n+1/(n\sqrt n), n \ge 2$ even and of course one can concoct tons of examples

Comment: But there are also tons of examples of alternating series which are not convergent if $z_n$ is not a monotonic sequence and in that case the inequality $|s-s_{n}|≤z_{n+1}$ would be a nonsense.

Comment: @Angelo (for above comment)  you are forgetting that, it is already given alternating series has sum $s$ so it is convergent. Hence i think we are not allowed to consider the non-converg ent series.

Comment: Hence does your proof works for convergent alternating series $\sum (-1)^{n+1} z_n$  in which $(z_n)$ is not monotonic?

Comment: @Akash, please read what I wrote in the beginning of my answer. We need additional hypothesis otherwise the inequality $|s-s_n|\le z_{n+1}$ is not always correct, in fact there are counterexamples. So it is impossible to prove the inequality if you do not add another hypothesis. If you do not like monotony, you need to add some other hypothesis in order to prove the inequality. If you do not add any additional hypothesis then the inequality is not always correct. Can you understand what I mean?

Comment: Is it possibile to prove the inequality if the only hypothesis is that the alternating series is convergence? No, it is not. Indeed there are counterexamples. But by adding other hypothesis it is possible to prove the inequality. I hope that this time I managed to say what I mean.

Comment: @Angelo so please  given me one counterexample. The example you given in answer, i think they are not considered as counterexample ( Because you considered series not convergent). Counterexample here must shows that, "if $\sum (-1)^{n+1}z_{n+1}$ is convergent and if $(z_n)$ is Not monotonic" then inequality does not holds.

Comment: $z_n = \begin{cases}2^{-n} & \text{ n is even} \\ 3^{-n} & \text{ n is odd }\end{cases}$ is not monotonic and the series $\sum(-1)^{n+1}z_n$ is convergent but the inequality does not hold. I wrote it in the beginning of my answer but I think you did not read it.

Comment: @Angelo can you please prove that, series given by you in above comment is convergent? (I think we cant use Alternating series series test because that requires that, $(z_n)$ must be decreasing)

Comment: See my second answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Property:**

If $\;\left\{z_n\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\;$ is the sequence defined as $\;z_n=\begin{cases} 2^{-n} \hspace{2mm}\text{ n is even}\\ 3^{-n} \hspace{2mm}\text{ n is odd}\end{cases}\;$ and $s_n=z_1-z_2+z_3-z_4+\ldots+(-1)^{n+1}z_n\;\;$ for all $\;n\in\mathbb{N}\;,\;$ then the alternating series $\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty \left(-1\right)^{n+1} z_n\;$ is convergent to the sum $\;s=\frac{1}{24}\;$ and $\;\left|s-s_n\right|>z_{n+1}\;$ for all $\;n\in\mathbb{N}$.

**Proof:**

The $n^{\text{th}}$ partial sum of the series is

$s_n=z_1-z_2+z_3-z_4+\ldots+(-1)^{n+1}z_n\;\;$ for all $\;n\in\mathbb{N}\;.$

Consequently,

$\begin{align}s_{2m-1}&=3^{-1}-2^{-2}+3^{-3}-2^{-4}+\ldots+3^{-(2m-3)}-2^{-(2m-2)}+3^{-(2m-1)}=\\&=3^{-1}\left[1+3^{-2}+\ldots+3^{-(2m-4)}+3^{-(2m-2)}\right]-2^{-2}\left[1+2^{-2}+\ldots+2^{-(2m-4)}\right]=\\&=\frac{3^{-1}\left(1-3^{-2m}\right)}{1-3^{-2}}-\frac{2^{-2}\left(1-2^{-(2m-2)}\right)}{1-2^{-2}}=\\&=\frac{3\left(1-3^{-2m}\right)}{8}-\frac{1-2^{-(2m-2)}}{3}\hspace{3mm}\text{ for all }\;m\in\mathbb{N}\;,\end{align}$

$\begin{align}s_{2m}&=s_{2m-1}-z_{2m}=\frac{3\left(1-3^{-2m}\right)}{8}-\frac{1-2^{-(2m-2)}}{3}-2^{-2m}=\\&=\frac{3\left(1-3^{-2m}\right)}{8}-\frac{1-2^{-2m}}{3}\hspace{3mm}\text{ for all }\;m\in\mathbb{N}\;.\end{align}$

Since $\;\lim_\limits{m\to\infty} s_{2m-1}=\lim_\limits{m\to\infty} s_{2m}=\frac{3}{8}-\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{24}\;$, it follows that there exists

$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} s_n=\frac{1}{24}$.

Hence the alternating series $\;\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty \left(-1\right)^{n+1} z_n\;$ is convergent to the sum $\;s=\frac{1}{24}\;.$

Moreover,

$\begin{align}\left|s-s_{2m-1}\right|&=\left|\frac{1}{24}-\frac{3\left(1-3^{-2m}\right)}{8}+\frac{1-2^{-(2m-2)}}{3}\right|=\\&=\left|\frac{3}{8}-\frac{3\left(1-3^{-2m}\right)}{8}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1-2^{-(2m-2)}}{3}\right|=\\&=\left|\frac{3^{-2m+1}}{8}-\frac{2^{-(2m-2)}}{3}\right|\ge\\&\ge\frac{2^{-2m+2}}{3}-\frac{3^{-2m+1}}{8}>\frac{2}{3}\cdot 2^{-2m+1}-\frac{1}{8}\cdot2^{-2m+1}=\\&=\frac{13}{24}\cdot2^{-2m+1}>2^{-2m}=z_{2m}\hspace{3mm}\text{ for all }\;m\in\mathbb{N}\;,\end{align}$

$\begin{align}\left|s-s_{2m}\right|&=\left|\frac{1}{24}-\frac{3\left(1-3^{-2m}\right)}{8}+\frac{1-2^{-2m}}{3}\right|=\\&=\left|\frac{3}{8}-\frac{3\left(1-3^{-2m}\right)}{8}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1-2^{-2m}}{3}\right|=\\&=\left|\frac{3^{-2m+1}}{8}-\frac{2^{-2m}}{3}\right|\ge\\&\ge\frac{2^{-2m}}{3}-\frac{3^{-2m+1}}{8}=\frac{1}{12}\cdot 2^{-2m+2}-\frac{1}{24}\cdot3^{-2m+2}\ge\\&\ge\frac{1}{12}\cdot 3^{-2m+2}-\frac{1}{24}\cdot3^{-2m+2}=\frac{1}{24}\cdot3^{-2m+2}=\\&=\frac{27}{24}\cdot3^{-(2m+1)} >3^{-(2m+1)}=z_{2m+1}\hspace{3mm}\text{ for all }\;m\in\mathbb{N}\;.\end{align}$

Hence, in any case it results that

$\;\left|s-s_n\right|>z_{n+1}\;$ for all $\;n\in\mathbb{N}$.